# How can I check if my list has only 2 specific elements that can be repeated?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I check if my list has only 2 specific elements that can be repeated?

For example:
Valid elements that I expect to be in my list are only 2:

```
1. abstract.f
2. None
```

If list has any other element, then it should throw an error message.

```
list1 = ['abstract.f', None, None, 'abstract.f']
# This is a valid list as it doesn't have any other element than 2 of above.

list1 = ['abstract.f', None, 'xyz']
# This is invalid list as it has 'xyz' which is not expected.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `all` to output a Boolean:

```
# Put items considered valid in this list
valid = ['abstract.f', None]

list1 = ['abstract.f', None, None, 'abstract.f']
print(all(el in valid for el in list1)) # True

list1 = ['abstract.f', None, 'xyz']
print(all(el in valid for el in list1)) # False
```

Comment: I was trying `list1` first and then `valid` in the `for`, thanks for correcting me!

Comment: Adding here, if the goal is to raise an exception: `if not all(el in [valid] for el in list1): raise ValueError('unacceptable value')`

Comment: Just a note here that empty lists return true

Comment: @StephenMason Mathematically speaking, an empty list would satisfy it, the condition being [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: @Tomothy32  I'd never seen that term before, interesting!

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to use `set` logic for this purpose:

```
>>> valid = {'abstract.f', None}
>>> list1 = ['abstract.f', None, None, 'abstract.f']
>>> list2 = ['abstract.f', None, 'xyz']
>>> set(list1) <= valid
True
>>> set(list2) <= valid
False
```

Answer (score 2):

can also check the number of matching list elements vs. the length of the list..i.e.:

```
result = list1.count(None) + list1.count('abstract.f') == len(list1)
```

will return True if the list only has elements that you have specified

to extend the idea for a larger case:

```
valid = [None,'abstract.f']
results = sum([list1.count(word) for word in valid])==len(list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rephrased, you can check that the [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics)) of elements in your list is a subset of the valid set of elements. Python has this abstraction built-in:

```
set(list1) <= {None, 'abstract.f'} # operator syntax
set(list1).issubset({None, 'abstract.f'}) # method syntax
```